# KML and Fusion Tables

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the different between KML and Fusion Tables ?
When it is possible to use them ?
what are the benefit and disadvantage of them ?

Regards,
Yossi

Comment: Does it releavnt only for google maps API ?

Answer (score 2):

As per the Google developer pages

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

> KML is a file format used to display geographic data in an Earth
>   browser such as Google Earth, Google Maps, and Google Maps for mobile.

It is basically an XML representation of geographic/spatial/location data.

[Fusion Tables](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=184641), on the other hand, are cloud based data tables that you can add/import data into.  You can then query these these tables in a number of different ways.  Google will also allow you to visualize the data in a number of different ways including in charts etc, as well as on a map.

How is KML and Fusion Tables linked?  You can store KML data in a column in a Fusion Table and Google will map the rows in the table against a Google Map.

Simples ;)